# What is correct way to call function inside setState(useState) hooks

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, state

> I want to update state at real time and call function inside setState but i am getting error.

onClick={() =>  setDetails(prevState => ({...prevState,id: product.orderId,status: 'processing'}) => updateStatus() )}

[image]

> Can someone tell me correct syntax and expression

Comment: Could you explain what are you trying to do here?
Cause right now in `setDetails` callback you are returning a function that runs `updateStatus` 

Comment: But your function arguments are in a wrong order, so it crashes

Comment: `useState` hook functions don't have a second argument like `setState` in class. you need to use `useEffect` instead

Comment: setDetails is basically hook (useState) so i want to call function inside setDetails

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are using `hooks`. You can't call a function in setState like in `class` components. You need to watch it through `useEffect`.

```
React.useEffect(() => {
  updateStatus() 
}, [state.id, state.status])
```

Comment: can't do this dear i am using this function many times.

Comment: please suggest something else to call function

Comment: I don't think the OP meant to update the state inside updateStatus. It should be a pure function. And if it updates the state, yea as you said it'll cause an infinite loop. OP needs to remove the status

Answer (score 0):

the function created using useState hook doest have a second argument. it will not support call back function  after updating the state. it was only there in the setState function which is used in class components.

You can use useEffect instead

```
useEffect(()=> {
   updateStatus()
}, [details])

   return (
     ...
    onClick={() => setDetails(prevState => ({...prevState,id: product.orderId,status: 'processing'}))}
     ...
    )
```

in this way, on every setDetails update it will call useEffect and then updateStatus